# Filter Function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, use-effect

My React app takes a list of employees from an api call. I have a similar function for a departments component that filters out the departments based on the name. When I do the similar thing for the employees, which have properties first_name & last_name. I get the error

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined`

But when I console.log the response, the names come thru no problem.

below is my useEffect hook I use

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (props.data !== undefined) {
      const results = props.data.filter(
        resp =>
          resp.first_name.toLowerCase().includes(filter) +
          " " +
          resp.last_name.toLowerCase().includes(filter)
      );
      setFilteredResults(results);
    }
  }, [filter, props.data]);
```

I place the filtered results into a state within an array and then map over them to display

Comment: So what exactly happens if you log the values of `resp.first_name` and `resp.last_name`?

Comment: they return both the last name and first name. so that is why I am confused as to why It gives my undefined when I call toLowerCase()

Comment: you should be returning boolean from the filter function not the value

Comment: how do you mean?

Comment: I mean it looks like you're concatenating two booleans with a space; this wouldn't filter at all. Filter checks if array elements match a condition (i.e. condition is `true`) however a non-empty string always evaluates to `true` and therefore you're not filtering at all. Just performing some ops and returning the same list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kind of hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do with your filter method, but `Array.prototype.filter` accepts a callback that, when invoked, is coerced to a boolean. If that boolean is true for a given array element, that result is included in the filtered list. If it is false, the result is not included.

Given that you're returning a non-empty string, all of the results will show up; I think this will get you closer to what you're trying to do:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (props.data !== undefined) {
      const results = props.data.filter(
        resp =>
          (resp.first_name && resp.first_name.toLowerCase().includes(filter))
          &&
          (resp.last_name && resp.last_name.toLowerCase().includes(filter))
      );
      setFilteredResults(results);
    }
  }, [filter, props.data]);
```

Use a simple value/null check to ensure `first_name` and `last_name` aren't undefined on `resp` before trying to access them.

Comment: Ok this worked pretty good, the only weird part is the search doesn't register the first character, for example I will enter Noah. The search won't filter on N, but does on O. not quite sure why that is.

Comment: @GeoffreyHutson Maybe try || instead of && that will include all items where firstname or lastname contanis filter.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the easiest way to avoid this would be to check first if `resp.first_name` is not null and then to call `toLowerCase` function.

Answer (score 2):

Your filter function should probably look like this, otherwise you're not returning a boolean but a string:

```
const results = props.data.filter(
  resp => (resp.first_name || '').toLowerCase().includes(filter) &&
  (resp.last_name || '').toLowerCase().includes(filter)
);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure he'll still run into `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined` with this

Comment: True, added a fallback to empty string to account for that.

Comment: same issue as I mentioned on the other answer, the search will filter out on O but not on N if I am searching for Noah